# How do I add and commit file in a git repository while in different directory

Tags: git

While working on a different directory, How do I run git commands like add and commit on a local git repository that is present in a different directory...?

I found the below command for getting the status..

git -C /Users/raj/Documents/Spring/spring-project-5/ status

But replacing 'status' with add or commit doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: `git -C <dir> ...` is equivalent to `(cd <dir>; git ...)`. If the files themselves are in your current directory *before* the `cd` part, they are not there *afterward* and you will need different paths to name them.

Comment: thanks for your help..

Comment: i was able to add and commit using the below comments using the below commands..

Comment: git -C /Users/rajkumarpurushothaman/Documents/Spring/spring-project-5/ add *

Comment: git -C /Users/rajkumarpurushothaman/Documents/Spring/spring-project-5/ status

Comment: git -C /Users/rajkumarpurushothaman/Documents/Spring/spring-project-5/ commit -m "commiting the latest"

Comment: Note that on Unix-like systems, `git ... add *` has the `*` expanded early: if it matches any file names in the current directory (before `cd`-ing), it gets replaced by those file names. However, in most shells, if it matches *no* file names, it is left as an argument to `git`. This is also the case with Windows cmd interpreter (but not bash). Here Git will expand it to "all files in the repository".

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a bash session, you also have the simpler option of:

```
pushd /Users/rajkumarpurushothaman/Documents/Spring/spring-project‌​-5
git add .
git commit -m "a message"
git push
popd
```

(using `git add .` here, not `git add *`)